# File name error in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: hard-drive, 20.04, external-hdd, filename

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 by getting rid of Ubuntu 18.04.2. I had backed up my data on an HDD before installation because I intended to wipe it all out.

There were no issues while transferring any files with colon (:) in their names to the drive, but now when I try to do the same I get an error.

Can anybody explain how this could have happened?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the error you got.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The solution I found is to mount the HDD as follows. First create the directory /mnt/nfts using "sudo mkdir -p /mnt/ntfs". Then, mount the HDD using "sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ntfs". By doing this, I am able to copy the files with : in the name. When you are done, use "sudo umount /mnt/ntfs". Please, note that I am not an expert and I really do not know if there are problems with this procedure, but it is the only one I found and I wanted to share it so that more experienced people can look at it and correct it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Is your drive formatted with fat32?  If so, that might be the cause of the problem, as fat32 does not allow colons in filenames.  In general, windows filesystems do not allow filenames with colons.

Can you access the other files from your upgraded ubuntu 20.04 system?  Are the files with colons in their name listed at all?  What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: I transferred thousands of files with colons in their names successfully into the HDD yesterday without any trouble. They are still there in the drive's storage. But when I tried to copy a file back an hour ago I got "There was an error copying the file into media. Invalid file name". My drive is formatted with FAT32, but that still doesn't explain the inconsistency between yesterday and today.

Comment: Please ask additional information through comments. Answers should only contain that, the answer. Indeed, you probably hit the nail with your assumption that this might be a fat32 partition, so the answer also is already there :-)

Comment: If FAT32 is the problem then how did those files get into the drive in the first place?